# Laravel Custom Raw Query Having

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to ask i have this kind of query

```
SELECT id,schedule, COUNT(schedule) as count FROM `games` GROUP BY schedule HAVING count > 1 ORDER BY `count` ASC
```

but the problem is, i don't know how to use "HAVING" in laravel query.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
DB::table('games')->groupBy('schedule')->having('count', '>', 1)->orderBy('count', 'asc')->get(['id', 'schedule', DB::raw('COUNT(schedule)')]);
```